# How to change Created By column's display format?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, ootb

I want to change the display format of **Created By** column in SharePoint 2010. It is right now displaying username like **LastName, FirstName**.

I want to change it's display format to **FirstName LastName**.

I want it to whole SharePoint site collection or web application if possible.

**Note:-**
*I do not want to use code for that.*

Comment: Is your AD display name in the last name, first name format?

Comment: Yes, in my AD i have set displaname = lastname, firstname.

Comment: The default mapping SharePoint does is use the display name from AD, so if you want a different format, you would need to have a new field in AD that has your desired format and remap the user profile field to this new field.

Comment: I have not done synchronization in central admin

Comment: I am in domain machine so it is getting logon user for SharePoint site

Comment: I have changed mapping in central admin for title column but it is not reflecting in site collection's User Information list.. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it using calculated column.

I have created one **Single Line of text** column named with **User** & make its value as calculated value to **=Me**. By that i get a user name like **corp\Hardik.Patel** (domain\username) in single line of text. after that i had made it hidden so it will not be shown into UI (add new form / edit form).

After that i have created one calculated column with having calculation like below

```
=PROPER(REPLACE((RIGHT(User,LEN(User)-INT(FIND("\",User)))),FIND(".",(RIGHT(User,LEN(User)-INT(FIND("\",User))))),1," "))
```

After doing all this, I am able to get the desire output in my calculated column as **Hardik Patel**.

Thanks for efforts. I really appreciated that. :)